# How to change the position of display objects which are inside a table

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I want to create a `table` with `display Objects` on specific positions. I wrote the following

```
for i=0, 5 do
      life[i] = display.newImage( "life.png"  )
end
```

but when I am trying this:

```
for i=0, 5 do
      life[i] = display.newImage( "life.png"  )
      life[i].x=i*Space_
end
```

compiler complains `attemp to index field ? nil value`

Any idea why this happen or how can I solve it? I want to use a for loop to add objects in a table (or maybe group? ) on specific positions.

Comment: Find a better title for this question. The error you are getting has nothing to do with changing positions of display objects. In fact, there are similar posts about "indexing field ? (nil value)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show us where **Space**_ is in your code.
Try this:

```
local SpaceX = 10

for i=0, 5 do
      life[i] = display.newImage( "life.png"  )
      life[i].x = i * SpaceX 
end
```

Comment: `Space_` is a global variable, its the width of the screen devided by 24.

Answer (score 0):

Corona doesn't find your image and returns `nil` as the result of `display.newImage` call. When you try then to access field `x` of a `nil` value, you get the error.

Make sure your image is available to your script.

Comment: if it couldn't find the image, it wouldn't show it on the screen I guess

Comment: there is nothing else in the code you shown that would trigger this error. Include line numbers with full error message.

Answer (score 0):

This assert should probably trigger, because life.png could not be found

```
for i=0, 5 do
      life[i] = assert(display.newImage("life.png"), "image could not be found")
      life[i].x=i*Space_
end
```